# IVR integration with .NET

Tags: .net, integration, ivr

Can anyone help me with some idea on how to integrate an IVR system with .NET application. What are the requirements and which are the providers which support .NET integration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeSWITCH has support for .NET. All you need to do is to activate the mod_managed module.

But you do not integrate a IVR application into a .NET application but code a IVR application in .NET. (Although you could use WCF or similar for communication between your app and the .NET code running in FreeSWITCH)

Comment: If i have IVR system in place with my client and want it to communicate or integrate it with my .NET application how do i go about it

Comment: it depends on what you used to make your IVR system and what you mean with communicate/integrate.

Comment: As an example if i have a client IVR which does a survey and i want a .NET application to communicate with this IVR system, then what would be setup like.

Comment: it depends on what you used (which platform/pbx/programming language) to make your IVR system and what you mean with communicate/integrate (database/sockets/ipc/other)

Comment: integrate or communicate essentially mean some kind of processing that is done by .NET on the data received from IVR system. Hope that helps. Since i am dvelving into it for the first time even i dont have much knowledge and so i can not provide a proper description. Let say there data from IVR will be processed to some format and entered in db.

Comment: Integration and communication can be done in several ways and it's impossible to give a proper answer without knowing what kinds of tools/programming language/platform you are using. It's like saying that you want to learn to fly without mentioning if you want to learn using a helicopter or jet plane. Try to fly a jet plane using knowledge learned from using a helicopter.

Comment: IVR system could be of CISCO or Genyses that client already has in place. I need to know how can our .NET application communicate with that system.                                                        Will the provider need to give the infromation as a web service or .NET application can be developed to interact with the IVR system to get required data.                                        Hope this describes the scenario.

Comment: @jgauffin: how to get installation path of freeswitch using WCF code?

Answer (score 0):

You can build an IVR fairly quickly with some help from Twilio tutorials.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-phone-tree/csharp/mvc

In this example, we walk you through how to build a typical call center workflow and the main menu to process a caller's selection in the IVR looks like this:

```
// POST: Menu/Show
[HttpPost]
public TwiMLResult Show(string digits)
{
    var selectedOption = digits;
    var optionActions = new Dictionary<string, Func<TwiMLResult>>()
    {
        {"1", ReturnInstructions},
        {"2", Planets}
    };

    return optionActions.ContainsKey(selectedOption) ?
        optionActions[selectedOption]() :
        RedirectWelcome();
}

private static TwiMLResult ReturnInstructions()
{
    var response = new TwilioResponse();
    response.Say("To get to your extraction point, get on your bike and go down " +
                 "the street. Then Left down an alley. Avoid the police cars. Turn left " +
                 "into an unfinished housing development. Fly over the roadblock. Go " +
                 "passed the moon. Soon after you will see your mother ship.",
                 new { voice = "alice", language = "en-GB" });

    response.Say("Thank you for calling the ET Phone Home Service - the " +
                 "adventurous alien's first choice in intergalactic travel");

    response.Hangup();

    return new TwiMLResult(response);
}
```

You can easily modify something like this based upon the needs of your application.